# No hosts file in xampp/etc directory?

Tags: apache, laravel, xampp

Can't find the hosts file. Have I accidentally deleted it? I have it set so hidden files are visible.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The hosts file is a system level file that acts as a supplement to DNS. It has nothing to do with any of the software distributed via XAMPP.

Look for it in `/etc/hosts` (or `C:\windows\system32\drivers\etc` if you use Windows).

Answer (score -1):

If you are on terminal, you can access the file by writing
"Sudo vim /etc/hosts "